# How do I get my 'urls' variable to update properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, scope, async-await

```
function getSitemapURLs( file ) {
  var urls = [];

  fs.readFile( file, ( err, data ) => {
    if ( err ) throw err;

    parser.parseString( data, ( err, result ) => {
      result = result.urlset.url;

      for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ) {
        urlObj = result[i];

        for ( var key in urlObj ) {
          if ( 'loc' != key) continue;

          // TODO: Improve how this key is accessed. Brittle.
          urls.push(urlObj[key][0]);
        }
      }
    });

  });
  return urls;
}
```

I'm running getSitemapURLs from a different file after requiring the method. If I `console.log( urls )` from within the `parseString` closure, it returns the expected value, an array of URLs.

Currently, when calling this from the index, I'm getting an empty array returned. This seems to be a scoping issue I've created. Can somebody help me scope this correctly so I can return the array of URLs?

This is what my index.js file is looking like, the file it is called from:

```
// Utility Methods
const getDomainParts = require('./utility/sitemap.js').getDomainParts,
      setSitemap     = require('./utility/sitemap.js').setSitemap,
      getSitemapURLs = require('./utility/sitemap.js').getSitemapURLs;

// Site Vitals
// Actual URL kept out of StackOverflow for privacy
const baseUrl   = 'https://www.xyzurl.com';
const directory = getDomainParts( baseUrl );

// Init Tests

( async () => {

  const sitemap = setSitemap( baseUrl, directory );
  await sitemap;
  const urls    = getSitemapURLs(`./sites/${directory}/sitemap.xml`);

  console.dir( urls );

} )();
```

Comment: This is not a scoping issue but an async issue.

Comment: @AndrewL I appreciate the insight. What do you think the async issue might be?

I've added in a copy of my index.js to the original post if that helps identify the problem at all.

Comment: Check out the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) here.

Comment: @AndrewL Seems to be nearly parallel to what I am experiencing here. I'll read through it and follow up with you. Thanks so much for the resource.

Comment: Glad I could help man. Cheers.

Comment: Is this function async? getDomainParts( baseUrl)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @CharisTheo, getDomainparts is not async